# How to make an application to capture video using Flash?

Tags: flash

I need to build an app. that will record video from the webcam, show the user what's being recorded and have buttons to start the recording, stop and send to the server.

Here at SO people said the easiest way would be using Flash, but I never used it and searching the web it's being kind of confuse so where should I start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires two steps. Displaying web cam input is the first step and recording it is the second. There is an excellent example of how to access a users camera in the AS3 language reference.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/

For recording check out the open source Red5 server. It allows you to capture audio and video.
http://osflash.org/red5

I believe recording is also possible with the Flash Media Server by Adobe. 
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/

Comment: Ok, but I don't understant wether I should use Flash Builder or Flash Pro. I read Flash Builder is used to create Flash applications which would be my case ( right? ) and it uses MXML. Flash Pro. on the other hand is for making animations which would not be my case, but uses AS3, that you're recommending me. So what should I do?